# How to capture webview response in React Native?

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I'm having a Webview in my React Native web app. From that Webview it shows a form. After user fills the form it navigates to another web(I'm not adding any URL, it automatically done by that web view). I need to capture the API response of that web view. **Is that possible to do that? I tried with injectedJavascript. But it's not working.**

Also I need to get the title of every web view. This is what I tried. Nothing works.

To get title.

```
    handleMessage(event) {

        console.log(message.nativeEvent.data);
}


 <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <WebView
            style={styles.webView}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
            onMessage={this.handleMessage}
            injectedJavaScript="window.postMessage(document.title)"
            source=
            {{uri: 'https://myweb.com/tokenization?type=usersave&automation=yes', 
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, method: 'POST',
            body: 
            'invoiceNumber='+invoice+'&storeName='+store+'&language='+setLanguage
        }}

            onError={() => {
                console.warn('ERROR');
            }}
        />
```

Comment: did you figure this out?